# Terraform interpolation data sources

Tags: terraform

I am configuring Terraform to provision virtual machines in VMware.  Each VM will be assigned a second network adapter connected with a specific VLAN. The VLAN is assigned based on the name of the VM

The data sources seem to query just fine, as they all exist.  However, I cannot pass the count.index into the  network_id in the network_interface section.
I have already tried the following:

1. `network_id = "${data.vsphere_network.network1."${var.policy_name}".id}"`
2. `network_id = "${"${format("%s", "data.vsphere_network.network1.${count.index}.id")}"}"`
3. `network_id = "${format("%s", "$${data.vsphere_network.network1.${count.index}.id")}"`

The only way it works is if I directly assign:

```
network_id = "${data.vsphere_network.network1.0.id}"
```

where 0 is the instance.

```
 data "vsphere_network" "network1" {
  count = "${var.count}"
  name = "${var.network_name1}-${format("%02d", count.index + var.start_index)}"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.datacenter.id}"
 }


 network_interface {
    network_id = "${data.vsphere_network.network1.0.id}" 
    adapter_type = "vmxnet3"
    use_static_mac = "${var.static_mac}"
 }
```

I expect VLAN 01 to be assigned to VM01. VLAN 02 to be assigned to VM02, going all the way up to 48(since that is the number of VLANs I have)

Comment: the network_interface block is nested within my resource block.  The only way I can get it to work is by specifying "${data.vsphere_network.network1.0.id}" - which will only point to one vLan and is not what I need. Anything I try converts it to a string and cannot be used. If I try dynamically assigning the number in ${data.vsphere_network.network1.0.id}, it will fail with a parsing error

Answer (score 1):

The following example uses Terraform 0.12 features to declare that there should be one instance per network and to identify each instance by its network id so that adding and removing networks in future will cause the appropriate instances to be added/removed too:

```
data "vsphere_network" "network1" {
  count = var.count
  name = "${var.network_name1}-${format("%02d", count.index + var.start_index)}"
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.datacenter.id
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "per_network" {
  # Create one VM per network and identify them using the
  # id value of each one.
  for_each = { for net in data.vsphere_network.network1 : net.id => net }

  # (...other virtual machine arguments...)

  network_interface {
    # each.key is the key from the map in for_each, which is
    # the network id in this case
    network_id = each.key
  }
}
```

Using `for_each` here has two key advantages:

- It makes it clearer to a future reader that the intent is to create one VM per network, because the network data resource is referenced directly in the `for_each` expression.
- It allows you to choose the keys by which Terraform will identify each of the instances when it tracks them in the state. Because the virtual machines are uniquely identified by their networks in this case, we use the network interface id and thus Terraform will be able to infer correctly that e.g. adding a new network should cause a new VM to be created, and removing a network should cause only the *corresponding* VM to be destroyed.

Comment: Hi Martin, I appreciate the post.  I tried implementing this and it says illegal character on the line that contains for_each = { for net in data.vsphere_network.network1 : net.id => net }.  Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: I failed to mention it was an illegal character on the colon

Comment: Which version of Terraform are you using?

Comment: the newest version,v0.12.6. I was able to get it working a little, but now my dynamic name in the resource block cannot use count.index. The vLans assign nicely, using the for_each. But now using the new terraform I cannot use count and for_each in same resource block. This is what I currently have: name = "${var.vmname}${format("%02d", count.index + var.start_index)}"

Comment: Indeed, you won't be able to use `count.index` in there because these instances are keyed by the network id rather than by position in a list. I'd suggest using a naming scheme like `${var.vmname}-${each.key}` instead, to reflect directly in the name which network it belongs to, so you can see easily which ones will be affected when changing the set of networks. Alternatively, if you really do want to use the index you could perhaps extract it from `each.value.name`, which will have the network number at the end of it.

Comment: Interesting. I thought I had tried that, and it stated that attribute didn't exist. Either way, each.value.name is the way to go for me.  Again, I appreciate your help.  You have been awesome.

Comment: Sorry, Martin.  Had a question regarding another change in syntax.

connection {
    host = 
 "${element(vsphere_virtual_machine.tfvm.*.default_ip_address,count.index + var.start_index)}"
    type = "winrm"
    user = "${var.tmpl_account}"
    password = "${var.tmpl_passwd}"
  }
This connection block passes through an object and works on versions earlier than v0.12.6.  When I try to use what is current set for host, it says that the object does not contain and attribute for default_ip_address.  Is there another level of the object I need to hit in order to access the default ip?

Comment: Of all the many examples of how to do this, this is the right way, and should be documented elsewhere as much as possible.